# How to ensure that only table row will be created with a particular state?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, concurrency, transactions

I have a domain object that looks something like this:

```
class UserStuff 
{
    String userid;
    boolean primordial;
}
```

In the table, *primordial* is a *TINYINT*. A **User** can have possibly many **UserStuff**. What I want to ensure is that only one row (the first row created) will have primordial == 1. All subsequent rows will have primordial == 0. At a glance, there is nothing to worry about. Let's suppose multiple creation requests for **UserStuff** may happen at the same time, how can I guarantee this constraint ?

My initial idea is to sync on a string (in the domain service)

```
class DomainService
{
    public void create( UserStuff stuff )
    {
        synchronized( stuff.userid + "/userstuff/lock" )
        {
            ...

        }
    }
}
```

I would love to hear comments about this & alternative methods. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The SQL approach, generally speaking, is to make `(userid, primordial)` a unique compound key, and use the `INSERT` statement with a clause of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` -- which sets `primordial` otherwise (but I'll admit I'm not sure what happens if the `UPDATE` also hits a duplicate, as it would when you insert the *second* non-primordial `UserStuff`).

Alternatively, with suitably isolated transactions, you could first `SELECT` to check if that `userid` is already present, then within the same transaction `INSERT` with appropriate values of `primordial`.

The SQL approach would be more solid if you ever have updates from multiple processes (maybe on different client nodes), but maybe if you're 100% sure that will never happen your Java-sychronization based ideas might get better performance... I won't guess one way or another, but recommend you measure things both ways (*if* you're willing to bet your shirt on never, **never** getting updates from multiple client nodes, that is;-).

`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, so I'll have to read up on that. There is possibility of getting multiple client updates, so concurrency is a problem I'll have to handle.